# how to select character varying data properly in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, select

I tried to select a data which is in column "fileName" and its fileName is '2016-11-22-12-55-09_hyun.png'
I tired the

```
select * from images where 'fileName' like '2016-11-22-12-55-09_hyun.png'
```

However it can not select anything, nor has any kind of error info.

How can I select this file with its filename? Thank you so much.

Comment: `... where  fileName like '2016-11-22-12-55-09_hyun.png'` ? or even  `... where  fileName = '2016-11-22-12-55-09_hyun.png'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes denote a string literal. So in this query you aren't evaluating the column `filename`, but checking whether the **string** `'filename'` is like the **string** `'2016-11-22-12-55-09_hyun.png'`, which it of course is not. Just drop the quotes from `filename` and you should be OK. Also note that since you aren't using any wildcards, using the `like` operator is pretty pointless, and you could (should) just a plain old equality check:

```
select * from images where fileName = '2016-11-22-12-55-09_hyun.png'
-- No quotes -------------^--------^
```

Comment: Thank you. In fact the column fileName has an upper case 'N', so if I drop the quotes, it will has error:"column "filename" does not exist". However you point out that single quotes is for checking string. That make great sense! I changed the single quotes to double quotes and it solve the problem! Thank you so much!